# Property of representable functor.

Tags: category-theory

Let $F\colon  C \rightarrow Sets$ be a representable functor, say $F \simeq C(c, -)$.

I want to put $$Nat(F,F) \simeq Nat(C(c, -), F)$$
 in order to get the center of the category $C$ for $F$ the identity functor via Yoneda Lemma.

Can I make such a move? Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In fact, by Yonda, $\text{Nat}(F,F)$ is canonically isomorphic to $C(c,c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make such a move. $\operatorname{Nat}(-,F)$ is a contravariant functor from $[C,\operatorname{Sets}]$ (the category of functors $C \to \operatorname{Sets}$) to $\operatorname{Sets}$. Functors always send isomorphisms to isomorphisms, so $\operatorname{Nat}(-,F)$ sends the isomorphism $F \simeq C(c,-)$ to an isomorphism $\operatorname{Nat}(F,F) \simeq \operatorname{Nat}(C(c,-),F)$.

---

As a broader aside for future reference, there is a "[principle of equivalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence)" that applies very strongly in category theory: if two things are equivalent by the appropriate categorical notion (which is almost always isomorphism), they can be used interchangeably in any well-formulated situation. This can be made precise in some frameworks: refer to the [univalence axiom](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/univalence+axiom) in type theory.

Note that nothing so sophisticated as the univalence axiom is necessary to show the fact you're asking about; I'm just pointing it out for your general education.